# selecting data which are in the same row

Tags: python, mysql

[my tabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI8FQ.png)

I need to know how can I make a code that do like this:

> if quiz_num_1 data was not quiz_null for the account_id 2 make a print and if quiz_num_1 data was quiz_null for account_id 2 make a diffrent print the account_id can be controlled by a variable name:user_account_id = 1 or 2

can anyone help me?

I tried to do this and not working

```
mycursor.execute(f"SELECT account_id FROM quizzes_lib WHERE account_id = '{user_account_id}'AND SELECT quiz_num_1 FROM quizzes_lib WHERE quiz_num_1 = 'quiz_null'")
 #mycursor.execute("SELECT quiz_num_1 FROM quizzes_lib Where quiz_num_1 = 'quiz_null'")
 if mycursor.fetchall():
   print("there is no quizzes in your library")
 else:
   print("there is __ in your library")
```

Comment: Your SQL might work better as `f"SELECT account_id, quiz_num_1 FROM quizzes_lib WHERE account_id = '{ user_account_id }' AND quiz_num_1 = 'quiz_null'"`

Comment: it worked when i changed
AND quiz_num_1 = 'quiz_null' to AND quiz_num_1 != 'quiz_null'
thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
mycursor.execute(f"SELECT account_id, quiz_num_1 FROM quizzes_lib WHERE account_id = '{ user_account_id }' AND quiz_num_1 != 'quiz_null'")
if mycursor.fetchall():
  print("there is quizzes in your library")
else:
  print("no quizzes")
```